# Glossy Text shader material on soft toch paper

Tags: shaders

I can't get the right shader material for text like this:

[image]

I've used a texture uvmapped on a plane, with alpha channel, and assigned two shaders one Glossy and one Glass with IOR of 1.406 (plastic) without succes.

Comment: A simple glossy material for the text/designs would work, the lighting is what you would need to change.

Comment: It's not so simple, because the text is like a rubbered glossy plastic. Transparent on surface paper.

Comment: Do you have a reference image to work from?